# Laravel Rest API - Get specific columns in json

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, laravel-5

i'm building Restful API Using Laravel

what i wanna to do is to get specific columns in JSON response instead on get all column

For example
I've Product Table with these columns

```
title - price - description - status - created_at - updated at
```

and i just want to show **title**, **price** and **description** in JSON Response

So, any idea to do that?

Comment: Post your query code

Comment: There's many ways to do this and which one you should use depends on your specific requirements. For example you could use [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources)

Comment: I support the notion of resources, since you are building an API resources are standard

Answer (score 3):

You can use `select` for certain field display :

```
Model::select('title', 'price', 'description')->get();
```

Or, in `get()` method :

```
Model::get(['title', 'price', 'description']);
```

As you would like to make some typically visible attributes hidden on a given model instance, you may use the makeHidden method :

```
$data = Model::all();
$data->makeHidden('price');
```

Now `price` will be hidden from your query.

Comment: You can also  return Model::select ('field')->get() and Laravel will return json

Comment: is this way source?

Comment: @Jimmy here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#selects

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function after get() or all() method.

EX:

```
Model::all()->map(function($product) {
    return [
        'title',
        'price',
        'description'
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map only function which will give you the benefit that it also handles computed fields and not only "physical" SQL fields:

```php
Model::get()->map->only([
      'title',
      'price',
      'description'
]);
```

The Answer from Abu Bin Oalid above does not work, it gives you just the attributes, and not the actual values.